# Get the last trading day of the month (in Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

On a daily timeframe, how can I know whether the current bar is the last one for the current month?

I wrote a small script that uses the `month[1] != month` condition to find out this (see below). But the problem is that it will only indicate me the last trading day of the month on the following day, meaning on the 1st of the next month. That's why I am using the `offset=-1` argument for the plot instruction.

If for example the current bar date is July 31, I would like the script to alert me right on that bar (the current bar), not on the next one (the first of August).

Is this possible, please?

Thank you!

Alex

```
//@version=5
indicator("Last trading day of the month")

var int last = na

if (month[1] != month)
    last := 1
else
    last := na

plot(last, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, offset=-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that will tell you how many days there are in a month. You should also account for the leap years.

Below is an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Last day", overlay=true)

f_is_leap_year() =>
    if ((year % 4) != 0)
        false
    else if ((year % 100) != 0)
        true
    else if ((year % 400) == 0)
        true
    else
        false

f_get_last_day() =>
    if (month == 1) or (month == 3) or (month == 5) or (month == 7) or (month == 8) or (month == 10) or (month == 12)
        31
    else if (month == 4) or (month == 6) or (month == 9) or (month == 11)
        30
    else
        f_is_leap_year() ? 29 : 28  // February

is_last_day = (f_get_last_day() == dayofmonth)

bgcolor(is_last_day ? color.blue : na)
```

[image]

Please note that, this will not consider when the market is closed (holidays, weekends etc.). It will just find the last day of the month.

Comment: Is there any way to get the last *trading* day of the month? So, the code should mark a trading day as "last" even if that day is not the last calendar day for that month.

Comment: I'd like to use this to plot some daily data [using `indicator (timeframe="D")`] on a monthly chart. But for this I need to know the last trading day for each and every past month. Otherwise, the data won't be plotted.

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible.